# Query Efficiency: Bad in Gestalt; Fast in Parts

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

My query is structured as 3 joined subqueries against a very large, powerful database.  The database sends 'older' data to an archive schema, without making any changes to the data structures.  Thus depending on how old the topic is I'm investigating, my query might point to the archive schema, or the production schema tables.  When I run my query against archive schema, it runs in about a minute.  When I run against production, it doesn't finish after an hour.

Confusingly, The Explain Plan of production version of query shows it to be much more efficient, than the archival version.

The form of the query is basically:

```
SELECT 
  SUB1.*,
  SUB2.*,
  SUB3.*
FROM ( BLAH BLAH BLAH ) SUB1
JOIN ( BLAH BLAH BLAH ) SUB2 ON SUB1.FIELD_11 = SUB2.FIELD_21
JOIN ( BLAH BLAH BLAH ) SUB3 ON SUB1.FIELD_12 = SUB3.FIELD_31
                           AND  SUB2.FIELD_22 = SUB3.FIELD_32
;
```

Referring to the Production version:

When I run only subquery SUB1 it returns 468 rows in 1.22 seconds.

When I run only subquery SUB2 it returns 807 rows in  .44 seconds.

When I run only subquery SUB3 it returns 63,106 rows in 27 seconds.

The two fields being used in the SUB3 JOIN statement are both indexed fields in the single table composing the SUB3 subquery.

The database is very powerful.

Why does the query run in parts relatively quickly - but slowly when all together.  If I had the db-rights I could write each subquery to a temp table and run the 3 part join and expect it to run in less than a second.  Why isn't the engine doing this?

EDIT:
Here is the explain plan.
[image: Problem Query Explain Plan]

EDIT:
Here is the explain plan for the archive schema version of the query (identical except in schema name, and actual table data is different).  This query runs in a about a minute and returns a few thousand rows as expected.  It seems to be much more expensive based on the explain plan - how could this be?

[image: Explain Plan]

Comment: Run an explain plan, and post the results

Comment: It may be using the wrong join order. I agree with @OldProgrammer, run the explain plan and post the results.

Comment: how many rows will get after join 3 tables? anyway explain plan will help to get more insight so post that

Comment: @Gaj, I'm expecting a few 1000 rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, That's not what I was asking about.  If each subquery can be run quickly - why is the 3-way join not completing even after an hour?  I would expect the engine to achieve just a little less efficient than the additive of the 3 subquery times.

Answer (score 0):

I change the order of my joins from 1,2,3 to 2,1,3.  This allowed the query to run and complete (a first).

I have no idea why, so I won't accept this as a solution.